# Flatten nested JSON data into SQL Server tables

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a JSON file that contains transactions, and each transaction contains multiple items. I need to flatten the data into SQL Server tables using T-SQL.

I have tried different options to flatten it, but it looks like I am missing something. Anyone who has worked on a similar structure have any ideas how this could be accomplished?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @json = JsonPath
FROM [dbo].[stg_transactionsJson] b;

SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.orderId')) AS orderId,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.openTime')) AS openTime,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.closeTime')) AS closeTime,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.operatorId')) AS operatorId,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.terminalId')) AS terminalId,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(c.Value, '$.sessionId')) AS sessionId,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.productGroupId')) AS productGroupId,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.productId')) AS productId,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.quantity')) AS quantity,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.taxValue')) AS taxValue,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.value')) AS ProductValue,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(150), JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.priceBandId')) AS priceBandId,
    GETDATE() AS DateUpdated
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json) AS c
OUTER APPLY 
    OPENJSON(c.Value, '$."products"') AS p;
```

And the sample JSON as follows

```
{
  "orderId": 431,
  "openTime": "2022-10-31T13:12:28",
  "closeTime": "2022-10-31T13:12:32",
  "operatorId": 7,
  "terminalId": 4,
  "sessionId": 1,
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": 2632,
      "productGroupId": 162,
      "quantity": 1,
      "taxValue": 0.58,
      "value": 3.5,
      "priceBandId": 2
    },
    {
      "productId": 3224,
      "productGroupId": 164,
      "quantity": 1,
      "taxValue": 0.08,
      "value": 0.5,
      "priceBandId": 2
    }
  ],
  "tenders": [
    {
      "tenderId": 2,
      "value": 4.0
    }
  ],
  "type": 1,
  "memberId": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output defines the exact statement, but if you need to parse nested JSON content you may try a combination of:

- `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema and the `AS JSON` modifier for nested JSON
- additional `APPLY` operators for each nested level.

T-SQL:

```
SELECT
   j1.orderId, j1.openTime, j1.closeTime, j1.operatorId, j1.terminalId, j1.sessionId, j1.type, j1.memberId,
   j2.productGroupId, j2.productId, j2.quantity, j2.taxValue, j2.productValue, j2.priceBandId,
   j3.tenderId, j3.tenderValue
FROM stg_transactionsJson s
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(s.stg_transactionsJson) WITH (
   orderId NVARCHAR(50) '$.orderId',
   openTime DATETIME '$.openTime',
   closeTime DATETIME '$.closeTime',
   operatorId NVARCHAR(50) '$.operatorId',
   terminalId NVARCHAR(50) '$.terminalId',
   sessionId NVARCHAR(50) '$.sessionId',
   products NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.products' AS JSON,
   tenders NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.tenders' AS JSON,
   type int '$.type',
   memberId int '$.memberId'
) j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.products) WITH (
   productGroupId NVARCHAR(50) '$.productGroupId',
   productId NVARCHAR(150) '$.productId',
   quantity NVARCHAR(50) '$.quantity',
   taxValue NVARCHAR(150) '$.taxValue',
   productValue NVARCHAR(50) '$.value',
   priceBandId NVARCHAR(150)'$.priceBandId'
) j2
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.tenders) WITH (
   tenderId NVARCHAR(150) '$.tenderId',
   tenderValue NVARCHAR(50) '$.value'
) j3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Creating another CTE with tenders solved the issue for tenders. How would it be possible to apply this at the table column level?

Comment: @Jobin, with an additional `APPLY` operator. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can Do it like this

First declare the values in an with clause and then cross apply the products

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
  "orderId": 431,
  "openTime": "2022-10-31T13:12:28",
  "closeTime": "2022-10-31T13:12:32",
  "operatorId": 7,
  "terminalId": 4,
  "sessionId": 1,
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": 2632,
      "productGroupId": 162,
      "quantity": 1,
      "taxValue": 0.58,
      "value": 3.5,
      "priceBandId": 2
    },
    {
      "productId": 3224,
      "productGroupId": 164,
      "quantity": 1,
      "taxValue": 0.08,
      "value": 0.5,
      "priceBandId": 2
    }
  ],
  "tenders": [
    {
      "tenderId": 2,
      "value": 4.0
    }
  ],
  "type": 1,
  "memberId": 1
}
';
SELECT c.orderId
  ,c.openTime
  ,c.closeTime
  ,c.operatorId
  ,c.terminalId
  ,c.sessionId
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.productGroupId') productGroupId
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.productId') productId
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.quantity') quantity
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.taxValue') taxValue
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.value') value
  , JSON_VALUE(p.Value, '$.priceBandId') priceBandId
  ,GETDATE() AS DateUpdated
  FROM
  OPENJSON(@json)  WITH (
  orderId int '$.orderId',
  openTime date '$.openTime',
  closeTime date '$.closeTime',
  operatorId int '$.operatorId',
  terminalId int '$.terminalId',
  sessionId int '$.sessionId',
  [products] NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON) c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.products) p
```

| orderId | openTime | closeTime | operatorId | terminalId | sessionId | productGroupId | productId | quantity | taxValue | value | priceBandId | DateUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 431 | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-31 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 162 | 2632 | 1 | 0.58 | 3.5 | 2 | 2023-01-11 13:57:47.607 |
| 431 | 2022-10-31 | 2022-10-31 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 164 | 3224 | 1 | 0.08 | 0.5 | 2 | 2023-01-11 13:57:47.607 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7u8yEsq4)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, How it could be if I have to use this in a table column ? It might take a lot of resource if I have to run it in a loop. Also how could I handle the tender block ?

Comment: you need to add another  apply with tender , for the table you need another join **before** the open json

Comment: That is solved thanks, having problem only in applying the same into the table which has got the JSON column.